# Cloud Firestore for webapp

Tags: javascript, webview, android-webview, stripe-payments, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using plaid for ACH payments in Stripe.I want to use it for android but documentation is in javascript.so I used webView in android.So when the user gives his ACH bank details in a HTML page, those values will be converted as tokens and need to store in cloud firestore.But the problem is the values are not storing in cloud firestore.Here is HTML page I used for the purpose

```
<button id='linkButton'>Proceed To Pay</button>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAhhxfqpoILYEA1Pnt7ciRpRm_hniJ3HUc",
    authDomain: "wallet-d66d9.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://wallet-d66d9.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "wallet-d66d9",
    storageBucket: "wallet-d66d9.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1040078578516"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>

<script>
var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
  env: 'sandbox',
  clientName: 'Stripe/Plaid Test',
  key: '19cf65eeb2a40ac3e397ebb0e76072',
  product: ['auth'],
  selectAccount: true,
  onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
    // Send the public_token and account ID to your app server.
    //var current = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var dbRef = db.collection('deyaPayusers').doc("CDF6BVM4TXSOwAt0tVlUQTliBx53").collection('plaid').add({
    pubToken : public_token,
    acctId : metadata.account_id}).then(ref => {
    console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);
});
    console.log('public_token: ' + public_token);
    console.log('account ID: ' + metadata.account_id);
  },
  onExit: function(err, metadata) {
    // The user exited the Link flow.
    if (err != null) {
      // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior to exiting.
    }
```

When I executed the file using the browser the data is storing in firestore, but when I used in webView, it is not storing data.I followed the same rules for the web in the HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one wants to use plaid for mobile devices using webview it is the correct method and plaid provides examples for plaid integration in mobile devices.Here is the link https://github.com/plaid/link follow it and change the keys.